# mail goes to spam (gmail) using vesta panel

Tags: email, gmail, digital-ocean, spam, vesta

[mail-tester.com results](https://www.mail-tester.com/web-ktxi3) is 10/10

but send mail to gmail via roundcube, mails goes to spam.

gmail receive info:

```
Delivered-To: abdurrahimak@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:ac9:1d47:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id r7-v6csp1746391och;
        Thu, 7 Jun 2018 06:13:49 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ADUXVKKprZ2ybuoUQOSmuaEi+0kLKiBTel5fcbAQEKn8AjNazh752opgh6IZf/vrXYirfbtczVrh
X-Received: by 2002:adf:f18b:: with SMTP id h11-v6mr1831062wro.214.1528377229401;
        Thu, 07 Jun 2018 06:13:49 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1528377229; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=DP1kpmoEB62hZMaMu499xkiPKuc3YHAn0EIXhgYe6SOjOZtk0WuvaGkZ4lfIL+KXQb
         MtQLEyy1BLWYzZaS45nURVTLe2EVYATgXyvkO3jiC4dOi9hn8sQPmfKyr5if43fvueA/
         yZbZpDi0+COhBnvplQHNfMCvGcD3U5pBbP12440J9nn5wt0E8zZClASFVJdC/EKgkBp9
         wWBBHgXpT/fuUTNJnknq6Chlr4YrlutHqgOHbuOP+pqwlPVR8Rtm9k/4moKa8GF/QC7c
         T2HCJpg4EJ+pEmCoJQqhJlQJTrKXeTWmYZo1FCzQNg+PFvBfjzdrlxigPJx2cIy6o2KH
         eXiA==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=user-agent:message-id:from:date:content-transfer-encoding
         :mime-version:subject:to:dkim-signature:arc-authentication-results;
        bh=vmN648Na0Mc7LR3f7sexUyWXvcMwFUhlOCIwybiWkbM=;
        b=w0SWhtSiqHwh6Og0/zxQUc7bq4uwrrDPGx4Ka6hiCMILASqnT6HGKHWj7i8PVci2mn
         KnYvuji63h9CX6KptEl9+6kFpoP942oEmmFIfavi6acHTgZyBB/J7Z1tPRae+MUvfOz8
         tjmT4CEMjyTpQSPY4kDfdlold36DtXP1DjAkGE0b5GLlbxArwp4xKX5VY9Z9WzL1FqbM
         gCt1+3Tg/Yj2YOmxgn44guARCpXupe++136LauKw0pLLyxL+1oqg54JkO5NNRI1cx83M
         I0cuRFdkXYkAxzFW15cxHnBO2+c7oLVTeczLY4W2X+rqS8xpVh8S8iUJX0grZfZ3h/i2
         8uoQ==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@sudobilisim.com header.s=mail header.b=aP7Lg05s;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of info@sudobilisim.com designates 206.189.61.232 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=info@sudobilisim.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=sudobilisim.com
Return-Path: <info@sudobilisim.com>
Received: from sudobilisim.com (sudobilisim.com. [206.189.61.232])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id r6-v6si1154475wma.177.2018.06.07.06.13.49
        for <abdurrahimak@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Thu, 07 Jun 2018 06:13:49 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of info@sudobilisim.com designates 206.189.61.232 as permitted sender) client-ip=206.189.61.232;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@sudobilisim.com header.s=mail header.b=aP7Lg05s;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of info@sudobilisim.com designates 206.189.61.232 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=info@sudobilisim.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=sudobilisim.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=sudobilisim.com; s=mail; h=Message-ID:From:Date:Content-Transfer-Encoding: Content-Type:MIME-Version:Subject:To; bh=vmN648Na0Mc7LR3f7sexUyWXvcMwFUhlOCIwybiWkbM=; b=aP7Lg05s4KWi3XdfoVN+qdcWFG 7Zh4dRHaL+/sWz2qdeinJpyww4UAZkOpnRVSphZbEavsT8F1tJr+seW1EwHLxRY5lzUkLRSqctimD a7hd33K/wMj56h4jsRkv/UYWZsow6wzJSZukvH6tlqC1OpqC6MwdkszB1BjfjmrcDG6Q=;
Received: from admin by sudobilisim.com with local (Exim 4.86_2) (envelope-from <info@sudobilisim.com>) id 1fQujc-000723-Tf for abdurrahimak@gmail.com; Thu, 07 Jun 2018 13:13:48 +0000
To: abdurrahimak@gmail.com
Subject: deneme
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:rcube.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Date: Thu, 07 Jun 2018 16:13:48 +0300
From: info@sudobilisim.com
Message-ID: <e8d39af15cef0ff00fe5671c036cc48b@sudobilisim.com>
X-Sender: info@sudobilisim.com
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/1.2-beta

sa kardeş
```

MXTools record:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GL74.png)

please help, I use vesta panel. MxTools said "SMTP Valid Hostname -> Reverse DNS is not a valid Hostname".

Digitalocean droplet name => sudobilisim.com (PTR) 
vesta panel hostname => sudobilisim.com (DNS-> childns)

Vesta panel sudobilisim.com dns list :

```
ns2 A 206.189.61.232
ns1 A 206.189.61.232
mail._domain... TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCyKPunug/SKDmSYSyadMTEYz2W37yNBC6JqfCmnn1dH2edcDhwYeJ2Eo8enemIVFJnuMyQeci62C+3REUqzkZgkCscQsC4TExYjB+D0ZzAxryxh26WXY/kfxoMAgTzoQ4kVXlHMo5AUHPpiHYa4Jr5eSvu6tp9NgZTFG8EJ62gsQIDAQAB"
_domainkey TXT "t=y; o=~;"
_dmarc TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none"
@ TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:206.189.61.232 ~all"
@ MX10 mail.sudobilisim.com.
imap A 206.189.61.232
pop A 206.189.61.232
smtp A 206.189.61.232
mail A 206.189.61.232
ftp A 206.189.61.232
www A 206.189.61.232
@ A 206.189.61.232
@ NS ns2.sudobilisim.com.
@ NS ns1.sudobilisim.com.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Reverse DNS (rDNS) resolves your IP address **206.189.61.232** correctly as *232.61.189.206.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer sudobilisim.com* , and then Forward confirms (FCrDNS) as *sudobilisim.com has address 206.189.61.232*

However the hostname **sudobilisim.com** doesn't have any MX records in its DNS, so isn't being considered as a valid mail hostname.